Repeat Date in Teradata Studio vs. SQL Data Assistant
I am new at my job and we use Teradata.  I am using Teradata Studio, and one of our longer Procedures starts with this statement:
SELECT                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                              
   '?Start_Period' as "Start Period",                                                                                                                                            
   '?End_Period' as "End Period"                                                                                                                      
        ; 

It will not run for me in Studio, but my manager and colleagues who use SQL Assistant with Teradata can run it.  Is there something I can use in place of the ? in studio that will give me the same result?
Thanks!
I have tried using ampersand with the same error code:

Data definition not valid unless solitary.


No quotes, and you need a \ between the ? and the parameter name - select ?\StartDate as "Start Period"

The QuestionMark is a feature in SQL Assistant (SQA) to parametrise your SQL. SQA will ask for the value to replace and then Search/Replace the parameter.
In TD Studio by default this feature is deactivated. You can activate it by clicking the "String Substitution" Button of the SQL Editor View. (In my case the 9th Icon on the top right direct to the SQL Text)
Unfortunately in some cases the Icon is hidden if you don't make the App FullScreen

Thank you!  This was the answer I needed!
